# Which of these sentences with "coerced into playing" are correct?

Tags: word-usage

> 1. I am coerced into playing along with him
> 2. If he comes, I will have to be coerced into playing
> 3. I am to be coerced into playing

Can I use those sentences above? Are those grammatically correct?

Found some sentences online which are probably correct...

> 1. The maid coerced her famous employer into paying her an exorbitant sum of money.
> 2. It took a lot of treats to coerce the cat into her carrier for a trip to the vet.
> 3. I don’t think anybody should be coerced into leaving.

Answer (score 1):

> 1.I am coerced into playing along with him

This is correct if you are speaking about something which is happening now. You are currently playing with him but you did not want to be. You might say I have been coerced into playing with the same sense and that would sound more natural to me.

> 2. If he comes, I will have to be coerced into playing

This one is fine

> 3. I am to be coerced into playing

That sounds awkward as a stand-alone statement. It might be better as I will be coerced into playing.